# Angular TranslateService instant method

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate instant('key') method and I have some keys for witch it does not have entries in language file so it should return key instead of translation.
I am using it in Pipe like this:

```
public constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }

public transform(stereotypeName: string): string {
    const stereotypePackage: StereotypePackage | null = StereotypeUtil.getPackageContainingStereotype(stereotypeName);
    const packageName: string = stereotypePackage?.name || '';
    const key: string = `stereotypes.${packageName}.${stereotypeName}.name`;

    const translated: string = this.translate.instant(key);
    ...
```

For most of the keys it does not find translation it returns full key like so:

```
'stereotypes.Basic Behaviour.E2ENew.name' -> 'stereotypes.Basic Behaviour.E2ENew.name'

'stereotypes.MongoDB.MongoDBOperation.name' -> 'stereotypes.MongoDB.MongoDBOperation.name'

'stereotypes.REST.REST.name' -> 'stereotypes.REST.REST.name'
```

but for one key it returns just last part of the key:

```
'stereotypes.SOAP.SOAPRPCOperation.name' -> 'name'
```

Is there any explanation why I am getting result like this, why it does not return the whole key as it works for first three examples?
I tried also with a get('key') and subscribe method but it gives the same result.